# How to format and validate birth date node js

Tags: node.js, angular, validation, date, express

I would like users would be > 18 years. So birth date entered should be > 18 years.

Which is the best way to do it?

I have a component for registration and I have the field like this:

```
<mat-form-field id="birth-date">
              <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" name="birthDate" [(ngModel)]="birthDate">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

In my usersRouter I have the function for registration:

```
router.post('/users/register', (req, res) => {
        ...
        const user = new User({
            ...
            birthDate: req.body.birthDate,
            ...
        });
     ...
});
```

Also, I use mongo and in the UserSchema I have this for the birth date:

```
birthDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using mongoose ?

Comment: Yes I'm using it

Answer (score 0):

Use moment for this. As you are using nodeJs then it should be fairly easy. `https://momentjs.com/` . You can use it in your router like this

```
var years = moment().diff(req.body.birthDate, 'years');
```

Now check if the years is more than 18 or not. If not then return error to the user in case less then 18. But the best would be to check it in front end and give an error there if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom validator in mongoose

```
birthDate: {
        type: Date,
        validate: {
          validator: function(v) {
            v.setFullYear(v.getFullYear()+18)
            const currentTime = new Date();
            currentTime.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            return v.getTime() <= currentTime.getTime();
          },
          message: props => 'You must be 18 years old.'
        },
        required: true
    }
```

**Reference:** https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html